# SQL Server Replication agent security settings error

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2012, merge-replication

When I try to change the account for the snapshot agent in a merge replication publication I am getting this error:

```
Cannot save changes to agent security settings.

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.      (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.
Changed database context to <removed>. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3930)
```

The account has db_owner permissions on the disribution database and the source database and also has full control on the replication share.  I've also tried setting it up with a domain admin account and get the same error so I think I've ruled out a permissions issue.

Comment: Is the user making the change sysadmin?

Comment: Yes I tried with sysadmin user